# fractions floating point number

Tags: ieee-754

What is the most efficient way to determine the significant places in a IEEE-754 64-bit floating-point number?

For example:

56.7899 --> 4
0.005 --> 3
-56.1 --> 1
768.0 --> 0
56.56000 --> 2

My current solution is to convert the float to string representation an determine the strlen of the remainder but that seems very inefficient.

EDIT: I applied a round() to six places on float64 instances to get rid of corner cases like 45.00000000000096

And I am only interested in the remainder part.

Comment: IEEE754 is in base 2, but your examples are in base 10. They don't fit nicely (for instance, `1.0/10` i.e. `0.1` does not have a finite exact representation in base 2), so your question does not even has a well defined meaning.

Comment: > so your question does not even has a well defined meaning How so?

Comment: Basile has the right of it: you can't do this because the values stored aren't decimal. I suggest you switch to using a representation akin to Java's `BigDecimal`.

Comment: I understand that perfectly. I also know that certain numbers in base 10 have no exact representation in IEEE-754. For an algorithm it is required to determine the number of places after the comma and currently I am doing it by converting to string which certainly is horribly inefficient. If I could get the remainder as integer or sthg. would already help.

Comment: I am not sure that converting to string is horribly inefficient. I don't claim it is efficient neither, but it might be good enough for your ill defined purposes.